# minDate and maxDate makes jQuery change year malfunction

Tags: jquery, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

This my code for some date field. If change year is used I don't get the `mindate` year. Why is that?

```
$(function() {
    $("#d_o_b").datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: " -54Y",
        maxDate: " -17Y"
    });
});
```

Comment: Which datepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: i use <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  &  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code

Comment: @mplungjan this is the code !!!

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. Share MCVE replicating issue

Comment: Google it... [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this has nothing to do with PHP....

Comment: @A. Wolff , today when i click change date the min year is 1989 & max year is 1999 why not that goes below 1989 in the first drill down ?

Comment: Oh i see **but why** don't you clearly explain your issue in question itself??? You need to use yearRange option `yearRange: "-54:-17",`   https://jsfiddle.net/vy2sjoe2/

Comment: @A.Wolff, thank you a lot.

Comment: Please delete the question

Comment: @Bineesh - When I said code I meant the code you pasted into the comment

Comment: @mplungjan. why you want the question to be deleted

Comment: No proper answer and limited usefulness for others. You can answer it yourself too

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by using the following:

```
$(function() { 
   $("#d_o_b").datepicker({
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true,
      yearRange: "-54:-17" 
   }); 
 }); `
```